# Finding strings from an rss feed

Tags: php

I am trying to make a system where I gather colour themes from adobe kuler by rss feed and put them into a new format.

The rss feed is layed out like this:

```
<kuler:themeItem>
   <kuler:themeSwatches>
     <kuler:swatch>
       <kuler:swatchHexColor>
```

However, I cannot enter any of those tags, due to the colon in the tag. This: `foreach ($item->kuler:themeItem as $item)` would return an error because of the colon.

Comment: What method are you using for parsing the data?

Comment: i am using simplexml. (simplexml_load_file($feedURL);)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to remove the namespace indicators from the XML string prior to passing it to the XML parser (the namespace indicators are the strings before the colons; in your case kuler) like so:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents( $feedURL );
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string( preg_replace( "/(<\/?)[^:]+:([^>]+>)/", "$1$2", $xmlString ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [XML->Array Funcs](https://github.com/gaarf/XML-string-to-PHP-array)

I'd suggest trying that.

The resulting array looks something like:

```
Array
(
    [themeSwatches] => Array
        (
            [swatch] => Array
                (
                    [swatchHexColor] => #000000;
                )

        )

)
```

**Test Code:**

```
require_once('xml2array.php'); // file with the linked to functions

$test = '<kuler:themeItem>
        <kuler:themeSwatches>
                 <kuler:swatch>
                     <kuler:swatchHexColor>
                    #000000;
                     </kuler:swatchHexColor>
            </kuler:swatch>
        </kuler:themeSwatches>
    </kuler:themeItem>
    ';


$a = xmlstr_to_array($test);
print_r($a);
?>
```